# I am using ttypescript and typescript-transform-paths

Tags: typescript

```
E:\ChattyProject\chatty-backend\node_modules\ttypescript\lib\patchCreateProgram.js:84
    tsm.createProgram = createProgram;
                      ^

TypeError: Cannot set property createProgram of #<Object> which has only a getter
    at patchCreateProgram (E:\ChattyProject\chatty-backend\node_modules\ttypescript\lib\patchCreateProgram.js:84:23)
    at loadTypeScript (E:\ChattyProject\chatty-backend\node_modules\ttypescript\lib\loadTypescript.js:21:56)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\ChattyProject\chatty-backend\node_modules\ttypescript\lib\tsc.js:8:46)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\ChattyProject\chatty-backend\node_modules\ttypescript\bin\tsc:2:1)
```

I am running

```
npm run build
```

in package.json

```
"build": "ttsc -p ."
```

please help me with the solution

I am expecting to run

```
npm run build
```

successfully

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```html
    you may have to uninstall ttypescript and 
     replace it with another package that does the 
  same


   npm install --save-dev tsc-alias


change script at build



"scripts": {
  "build": "tsc --project tsconfig.json && tsc-alias -p tsconfig.json",
}




then run build again ==> npm run build
```